# I want to over-ride or decrease the wait time(120 seconds) on a website which is using javascript

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I want to over-ride or decrease the wait time(120 seconds) on a website which is using javascript.....this is the website "https://onlinebooking.sand.telangana.gov.in"
You can see only 20seconds timer but after login there is 120seconds

[image: **Screenshot of source code**]

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    var interval;
        function countDown() {
            clearInterval(interval);
            timer()
        }
        var timer = function () {
            var counter = 121;
            interval = setInterval(function () {
                counter--;

                document.getElementById("btnRegister").disabled = false;
                document.getElementById("btnRegister").style.display = 'block';
                document.getElementById('lbltime').innerHTML = "Timer : " + counter;
                if (counter == 0) {
                    document.getElementById("btnRegister").disabled = true;
                    document.getElementById("btnRegister").style.display = 'none';
                    document.getElementById('lbltime').style.display = 'none';
                    clearInterval(interval);
                }
            }, 1000);
        };

})();
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Did you resolve this problem? If so, you might wish to supply your own answer explaining how you solved it and select that as the correct answer. You won't get any points for that, per se, but (1) it will close the question, and (2) future visitors may upvote your answer if they find anything you did to be clever / helpful / interesting.